# Multiple return arrows with values

Tags: tikz-uml

I am trying to get multiple return values from a function using the package `tikz-uml.sty`:
[tikz-uml project](http://perso.ensta-paristech.fr/~kielbasi/tikzuml/index.php?lang=en)

In case of an `alt` block, I would like a function to return two different values. However I cannot set any value for a return arrow alone:

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlseqdiag}
\umlobject[class=A]{a}
\umlobject[class=B]{b}
\begin{umlcall}[op={tata(i,k)}, return=1]{a}{b}
\begin{umlcall}[type=return]{b}{a} % I would like to set a return value for this call
\end{umlcall}
\end{umlcall}
\end{umlseqdiag}
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image: single call with two return arrows]

I tried to look into the source of `tikz-uml.sty`, but I must admit that I never really went that deep into `.sty` configuration and design...

How could I set a value for the first return arrow? Thank you for any insight you may have!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following seems to give the desired result

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-uml}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{umlseqdiag}
\umlobject[class=A]{a}
\umlobject[class=B]{b}
\begin{umlcall}[op={tata(i,k)}, return=1]{a}{b}
\begin{umlcall}[type=return, op=0]{b}{a}\end{umlcall}
\end{umlcall}
\end{umlseqdiag}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]